# Azure ML R script to choose labels with highest score in web service

Tags: r, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have an Azure Machine Learning experiment with thousands of labels.  When I run the web service I get a table with two rows (label name and label probability) but thousands of columns.  I would like to select just the 5 labels with the highest probability (and preferably sorted descending).  Anyone now an Azure ML Studio component or R script that can do this please? Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to send the model to the gallery so we can see everything?

Comment: Are you using the newer AML services with Workbench? It does not support R, only Python